# Is it possible to configure the vim tab completion <Enter> key?

Tags: vim

I like vim's tab completion, when I'm using a command it can help me complete the command, and when I'm open a file it can help me complete the path or file name.

But when I'm using it to complete the path, for example that I'm about to open `test1/vimrc` to edit, but I don't want to type the path manually, so I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

`test/  test1/  test2/`

This is the list for my directories, then I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to select the `test1/`. But now, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then vim will open the directory(However I don't want to do that).

I can only press <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>BackSpace</kbd> to select the `test1/` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to list all files in `test1/`.

Now my problem is, is it possible to configure if the select is a directory, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> will only select it but won't open it untill I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again? (like `oh-my-zsh` default tab completion configuration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press the down arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> this will select the directory